# Cannot assign to value: 'completion' is a 'let' constant in swift

Tags: swift

```
func uploadImage(imageData : Data, path : String,completion: @escaping (String) -> ()) {
    let storage = Storage.storage().reference()
    let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
    
    storage.child(path).child(uid).putData(imageData, metadata: nil) { (_, err) in
        if err != nil {
            completion = ("")
            return
        }
        //Downloading url and sending back
        
        storage.child(path).child(uid).downloadURL { (url, err) in
            if err != nil {
                completion = ""
                return
            }
            completion = ("\(url)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `completion` it a closure, you're supposed to *call* it (passing in whatever values it needs), not assign to it.

Comment: What's this?  completion = ("")

Comment: You can see the type of completion here: `completion: @escaping (String) -> ()` the -> meaning it's a _function_ that takes a string and returns void. It's not a string.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write `completion` like this `completion(<#value here#>)` not to assign it

```
func uploadImage(imageData : Data, path : String,completion: @escaping (String) -> ()) {
    let storage = Storage.storage().reference()
    let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
    
    storage.child(path).child(uid).putData(imageData, metadata: nil) { (_, err) in
        if err != nil {
            completion("")
            return
        }
        //Downloading url and sending back
        
        storage.child(path).child(uid).downloadURL { (url, err) in
            if err != nil {
                completion("")
                return
            }
            completion("\(url)")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to assign a value to completion parameter, you need to invoke it like following -

```
storage.child(path).child(uid).putData(imageData, metadata: nil) { (_, err) in
    if err != nil {
        completion("")
        return
    }
    //Downloading url and sending back
    
    storage.child(path).child(uid).downloadURL { (url, err) in
        if err != nil {
            completion("")
            return
        }
        completion("\(url)")
    }
}
```